# Total distinct General Ledger YTD totals in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

The below SQL script gives me line values of distinct general ledger accounts. I simply want them totaled to give me a combined value.

```
Select 
GLACCT_DESCRIP as "Service Income Account",
(TOTAL_BALANCE*-1) as "Dollars"

From 
V_GLACCT_DESCRIP,
V_GLACCT_CURRENT_BALANCE

Where 
V_GLACCT_DESCRIP.GLACCT_ID = V_GLACCT_CURRENT_BALANCE.GLACCT_ID
and V_GLACCT_DESCRIP.GLACCT IN ('495500-215','495510-215','495550-215','495560-215')
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this might help.

```
SELECT glacct_descrip, 
       Sum (total_balance) * -1 
FROM   v_glacct_descrip 
       INNER JOIN v_glacct_current_balance 
               ON v_glacct_descrip.glacct_id = 
                  v_glacct_current_balance.glacct_id 
WHERE  v_glacct_descrip.glacct IN ( '495500-215', '495510-215', '495550-215', 
                                    '495560-215' ) 
GROUP  BY glacct_descrip;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help SriniV. No total was placed at the end however.

Comment: Can you post a minimal, complete and verifiable example? Add some sample data and the expected output for that